# How to convert readings from a DIY capacitive liquid level sensor to a level?

Tags: capacitor, sensor

#### Background

I have made a tubular capacitive liquid level sensor ([This](https://www.reventec.com/product/ls100/) is a professional one, for example). A 555 circuit outputs a frequency that is inversely proportional to the capacitance. This is read into the microcontroller (Arduino Nano clone).

The sensor will be used for monitoring our water tanks that supply our house.
There will be this one for the tank that gets municipal water, and another one for the tanks that collect rain water.

It is communicated with (and powered) over a Cat5 cable acting as a Modbus trunk.

The sensor consists of a DIY probe, made of aluminum and PVC pipes, and a custom board (made with stripboard).
The main components of the custom board are:

- Arduino Nano
- NE555
- ISL81487LIPZ (MAX485 replacement; [DigiKey](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/renesas-electronics-america-inc/ISL81487LIPZ/1977367))
- DC-DC buck-converter

#### The problem

I have taken readings and put them into an Excel spreadsheet, along with the depth of water when they were taken. They seem to be logarithmic, but they are not. I have taken the natural logarithm and normalized the values, and plotted this versus the percentage of submersion of the sensor.

This is the graph:

[image: graph of readings]

X is percentage submerged, Y is reading. "Log Normalized" is the plot of the normalized logarithm values. "Linear" is the plot of the wanted values. "Diff" is the difference between the "Log Normalized" value and the "Linear" value for each pair of those values.

In the final application, I will have a reading, and will need to find the depth of the water the sensor is in.

Summed up,
**I need a way to translate a reading to a level.**

I need it it to be

1. easy to implement (I am not a master mathematician ;) )
2. work with 32-bit floating point numbers
3. fast

The reason it needs to be fast is because of other compensation algorithms that will need to be added, e.g. when the water level drops, the reading doesn't change immediately, it changes as the probe dries. These algorithms will need to call the level calculating one quite often.

#### What I Am Using at the Moment

I am currently using the formula described in my answer.
It gives acceptable accuracy (for the purpose of the sensor), is simple, is fast, and just "feels right".

#### Other Stuff

The spreadsheet is [here](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AtvcAGZ7KmQUgYxQcvVgj0wcyE7LdA?e=UDUxuO). Note: I am still actively using it. There are formulas in place (which my answer here is based on), and some other experiments off to the side.

Images of the Fritzing Breadboard, the electronics, and are [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iCB1k.jpg).
The Fritzing file is [here](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AtvcAGZ7KmQUgZpK7wl-PrvzAzFV9A?e=uuWS1A).
(I couldn't get Fritzing to comply with editing the schematic. It crashed whenever I moved more than one component at a time, or any large component.)

[Cross-posted on math.stackexchange.com.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4017715/can-anyone-identify-this-curve-produced-by-a-capacitive-sensor)

Comment: Why are you expecting a perfectly log response? As long as you know the curve, you can produce a look up table to linearise it?

Comment: I can get a pretty accurate trendline in Excel with a cubic equation on the original readings (\$R^2=0.99979\$). Fairly accurate too with just a quadratic (0.9939). I'd lean toward using the quadratic since cubic may be overfitting.

Comment: Justin did same as I ,  depending on acceptable tolerance error  2nd (1.2%) or 3rd order (0.1%) https://i.stack.imgur.com/3lvMN.png

Comment: Darryl, Have you considered the idea that it's almost entirely one type of dielectric (air?) at one end of \$x\$ and almost entirely the other type of dielectric (whatever?) at the other end of \$x\$ and that right in the middle it's 50:50? There are fringing fields involved and my gut tells me that what you are experiencing may be expected. I haven't sat myself down to work this before, so I'm not drawing upon any specific developed intuition. But I wouldn't have been shocked to see this kind of data.

Comment: It is quite possible that the frequency produced is inversely proportional to the _square root_ of the capacitance. However, we don't have a schematic, so we can't tell.

Comment: the `diff` looks like a result of a `.15 × sin()` function

Comment: Thanks for the ideas! @Adil I was expecting either a linear or log response, a log response because that is a capacitor's charge/discharge curve. Yes, I could create a lookup table, but I would prefer to have a single formula.

Comment: @Justin Thanks, I may end up doing this. I am only a Grade 9 student, so I have not learnt much about topics such as quadratic or cubic equations. Thanks for suggesting it.

Comment: @ Math Keeps Me Busy: This is possible, I will look into it.

Comment: @jsotola It being related to Sine hadn't even entered my mind! Thanks! I will look into this too.

Comment: I will try to post the schematic, some photos, and design notes tomorrow.

Comment: Building a calibration method into the microcontroller reading the output is really a good idea since you'd want to calibrate it to the fluid you're measuring unless you could be sure it was either uncontaminated or consistently contaminated.  Water can go from a decent insulator to a decent conductor just with variations in salt.

Comment: You could even add a float sensor at the top and bottom of range and make calibration automatic if one of these formulas suggested straightens out your graph adequately.

Comment: @K-H, Yes, I was going to have some form of self-calibration, which, besides ease of implementation and transferability to other applications, was then main motivation to use a single formula instead of a lookup table (or something like that). Using float sensors is something I have considered, but I decided that just having it know (possibly updating them automatically) the max and min values would be enough.

Comment: In Excel, adding Euler's number multiplied by the sine of the number gets accuracy to 7.29%, over the original 13.61%. Using `e^2` gets accuracy to 5.78%. Increasing the exponent increases the accuracy, no matter what it is increased to. It stops making noticeable changes beyond the 10th power.

Comment: The above works with any number, not just Euler's. It may be floating point error.

Comment: Adding just the cosine of the value gets the maximum error to 6.86%. Adding the arctan gets 9.77%. NOTE: I said "accuracy" in some of my comments above. I meant "maximum error".

Comment: @DarrylNoakes the reason for my suggestion is that the resonant frequency of a typical LC circuit is given by f = 1/(2*pi*sqrt(LC)).

Comment: I'd expect two linear fits - say above an below 0.4, to be quit an improvement, and 3 to 5 even better. Computationally that ilmay be as easy as any alternative.

Comment: Thanks, Russell. What do you think the best way implement this would be?

Comment: I am working on the same problem that you asked 12 months ago. I have done some research on the question is it possible to measure pF capacitance with an LM555. I'm stuck with one question Can you help me to answer this question: Does anyone have experience using pF capacitance at the LM555.
I explained more in the link below, I hope you can and will help me. https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/607149/what-is-the-minimum-capacitance-cx-on-lm555

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a satisfactory formula/algorithm for my purposes. It gets the maximum error to around 5% (max: 5.02%, mean: 2.49%), which is quite possibly measurement error. While less accurate than other methods, I find it more simple and "idiomatic."

**EDIT, 2022-03-14**: I had forgotten to halve the adjusted value after applying the formula, to get it back to \$[0, 1]\$ from \$[0, 2]\$ after adding the `sin`.

1. Let \$f\$ be the frequency reading.
2. Let \$r\$ be the normalized log of \$f\$, using predefined minimum (\$l\$) and maximum (\$h\$) expected values.
   $$r = {\ln f - \ln l \over \ln h - \ln l}$$
3. Let \$R\$ be the final result. Then
   $$R = {r + \sin {r\pi \over 2} \over 2}$$

Below is a simple implementation of the formula in C++. It is based on my actual code, and should compile fine with PlatformIO. (Note: In reality, this is packaged in a class, in a custom library. If anyone wants the code, ask in the comments and I will make it public it on GitHub.)

```cpp
/*
 * `reading`, and therefore `min` and `max` as well, is an integer.
 * (because that's how the FreqCount library gives it to you).
 */

#include <Arduino.h>
#include <FreqCount.h>

// minimum expected frequency: the frequency when the water is highest/deepest.
const uint32_t min = 423;
// maximum expected frequency: the frequency when the water is lowest/shallowest.
// 1440 is just a value I picked on the high end. I will be adjusting it.
const uint32_t max = 1440;

const double min_log = log(min);
const double max_log = log(max);

double calculate_level(uint32_t raw_reading)
{
  // Take the logarithm of the value and normalize it
  // (adjust it to be between 0 and 1, inclusive).
  double reading =  (log(raw_reading) - min_log) / (max_log - min_log);

  // Apply the formula.
  double adjusted = reading + sin((reading * PI) / 2);

  // Normalize back to [0, 1] from [0, 2] after applying the formula.
  double result = adjusted / 2.0;

  // Subtract from 1, because the values get higher as there is less water,
  // and we want the opposite.
  return 1.0 - result;
}

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);

  // Init FreqCount to measure the number of pulses per 1000 ms.
  FreqCount.begin(1000);
}

void loop()
{
  if (FreqCount.available())
  {
    double level = calculate_level(FreqCount.read()); // See NOTE
    Serial.println(level, 2);
  }
}
```

This is the resulting graph, using the formula above:
[image: graph of readings]

NOTE: I profiled my actual implementation reading the frequency from FreqCount and calculating the level (equivalent to the line that has a comment saying "See NOTE"). It takes, on average, 344 microseconds. That's fast enough for me :).

Answer (score 2):

You can use a cubic in 1000/reading:

```
static const float coeff[4]= { 1.62914270704482, -7.9851592788591,  38.5529790479781, -23.7806334509969}; 

x =  1000.0/(float) reading; 

//  Evaluate using Horner's Rule 
result = coeff[0];
for (int i=1; i<4; i++)  
    result = result*x + coeff[i];
```

I see a maximum error of +0.41/-0.58% of span at the given points and evaluation takes 1 divide and 3 multiplications so it should be pretty fast even on an 8-bit micro. Coefficients were optimized to minimize sum of squares of errors rather than worst absolute error.

Interested to see the comparison with your transcendental functions cos/log.

Comment: This is very interesting. I am probably going to use one of the formulas I showed in my answer, since I am going to make more of these sensors, and a single formula that may not need any tweaking, or a formula with just a single constant that needs tweaking, would be best. However, if one of them doesn't work out, due to accuracy or speed, this will definitely be my next approach. I have edited my question to explain why I need speed.

Answer (score 0):

This is trick. Capacitive level sensing works but needs to be calibrated for, like, everything. It seems that your output is referred to the circuit you are using.

Capacitance of a level sensor (well, capacitance of *anything*) is proportional to the area covered and to the dielectric coefficient. Here [Physics: LibreTexts: 8.2: Capacitors and Capacitance](https://phys.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/University_Physics/Book%3A_University_Physics_(OpenStax)/Map%3A_University_Physics_II_-_Thermodynamics_Electricity_and_Magnetism_(OpenStax)/08%3A_Capacitance/8.02%3A_Capacitors_and_Capacitance)

You have the usual physical explanation *and* some horrible curve integrals that derive the capacitance of the *cylinder plate* capacitor, which your sensor should be a kind of. That's of course in the ideal world.

Since your capacitor should be cylindrical (is it really? if there is skew or taper the geometry change and we are talking about sub-pF differences), capacitance should be dependant only to the cylinder length and dielectric. In total you should have, in parallel:

- The capacitance of the length in the fluid, plus
- The capacitance of the length in air, plus
- Some somewhat fixed capacity due to cabling and other things;

Also you will have some other capacitance to ground, depending on the material of your container. And shielding is useful too, a guard conductor helps against charge leakage (remember that commercial capacitance converter resolution is specified in femtoFarads).

Then you have the environment. This is fully fluid dependant. Often temperature dependant.

That said, it seems that something is quite wrong with your converter or transducer. It should really be a linear relationship between level and capacitance (often the air section capacitance is negligible).

For example look at [TIDA-00317: Capacitive-Based Liquid Level Sensing Sensor Reference Design](https://www.ti.com/tool/TIDA-00317)

The corresponding part is quite advanced but the application notes have many ideas on how to design the sensor itself (and the issue on the process)

Comment: The dielectric constant of fluid introduces the error.  as the two dielectrics are in series and both changing with level.  e.g. \$\epsilon _R=80\$ for water

Comment: Why in series? in a level sensor the air and fluid capacitor parts are in parallel

Comment: Yes could be in parallel if electrodes are parallel to the fluid

Comment: If it's a coaxial probe then it looks like the air capacitor in parallel with the fluid capacitor to me, @Tony. What have you got in mind?