# What is the minimum capacitance Cx on LM555

Tags: sensor, embedded, hardware, physics

I want to measure a capacitance between 10pF and 500pF and feed that information to a microcontroller.

I was wondering if a CMOS LMC555 configured in astable operation could do the job with the schematic below. The problem I have is that most LM555 charts you find in the datasheets show the relation between capacitance connected at the threshold pin and the frequency but they don't go lower than 1nF.  The specification doesn't say anything about the lowest value for this capacitor. Who reads the various input specifications sees that these are very high impedance and consume pA currents. So uA currents though R1 and R2 should not be an issue compared with the pA current going in to the inputs.

**Question:**

Does anyone have experience using pF capacitance with the LM555?  Can you tell me based on your experience what the minimum capacitance on this threshold pin can be?

Is there another better and cheap way to measure this capacitance?

**Some additional info :**

I did a simulation with an LM555. The two R1 and R2 resistors were 1M, and I used a variable capacitance between 50 and 550pF. I did see some nonlinearity for C=10..30pF. Beyond 30pF the frequency of the LM555 output followed quite well the formulas. This simulation didn't indicate any weird signal shapes or other problems. The frequency ran between 1.6KHz and 10KHz, good enough to be read in to a microcontroller for further processing.

Stray capacitance on the input is for me not an issue, the proposed [capacitor acts as a contactless dirty water level meter](https://www.linkedin.com/feed/update/urn:li:activity:6894187669237198850) (see link) of which the capacitance varies with the height of the water between 11 and 236pF. The microcontroller can solve the nonlinearity in case that is an issue, which I don't expect it to be.

This LM555 acts according the simulation quite well as a capacitance to frequency period length converter, and it's even linear according to the formulas used for the LM555. My only question left is: Has anyone tried to use lower than 1nF capacitors on an LM555?

[image]
[image]

Comment: With such large resistors, pay attention to the input current requirements on pins 2 and 6; also leakage current on pin 7. It would probably work with a CMOS 555.

Answer (score 3):

> Does anyone have experience using pF capacitance with the LM555? Can
> you tell me based on your experience what the minimum capacitance on
> this threshold pin can be?

In 1978 I designed and built a multimeter with capacitance measurement using an NE555. I arranged it to produce a pulse width of 1 μs per pF on the low range, as that was the resolution of my timer counter. It required 950 kΩ of resistance from pin 6 to +5 V. The wiring (including ~200 mm of coax cable) had a capacitance of ~65 pF. To null out the parasitic capacitance I used a 74C86 quad XOR gate to create a fixed delay which was subtracted off the pulse width to 'zero' the meter.

This had sufficient stability and linearity to 'accurately' measure capacitance from a few pF to 1 μF. I still use this meter today! Here's photo of the insides:-

[image]

Comment: 74C86. NE555. Yellow wire gimmic trimcap. Tubular.. capacitors! <cue Mike Oldfield music>  That's a blast from the past. Thanks for this photo.

Comment: Great to hear, even better 1978 these are the real diehards. I made myself a SMPS in the beginning of the '80 using an Elector design. it still works and I still use it. Thanks for sharing this info.

Answer (score 1):

It would be better to use a CMOS 555 if you want to use a 555. That allows much higher values of resistor so the frequencies are less and the much lower bias currents have less effect.

Eg. [LMC555](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lmc555.pdf). With a 1M\$\Omega\$ Ra + 2*Rb you'll get a bit over 1kHz with 1nF so 10kHz with 100pF and 20kHz with 50pF.

You can parallel a fixed stable (eg. NP0 ceramic) capacitance with the unknown capacitance and subtract the offset in your firmware. This depends on the capacitor leakage being low, however.

If that's not the case I think you would have think about something other than a 555 to have the leakage effect minimized.

You can probably go much lower than some tens of pF but I don't see much advantage and there may be unwanted effects from stray capacitances (for example, capacitance coupling *across* the timing resistors).

Comment: Thanks for your response. I checked the difference between the LM and LMC 555 and yes you are correct the LMC is better, I thought the LM was a CMOS version, but it's not and has different input current characteristics.      So in your opinion, 1) you can get lower than the 1nF then the LMC555 specification mention in their frequency graphs at page 9 and 11?  2) have you tried that?

Comment: Yes, you can go much lower, as I said above. < 100pF with ~1M resistors for sure. Linearity & then limits are set by *leakage* (compared to the timing resistors), *frequency* (don't get anywhere near the max for the chip) and  *stray & input capacitances* (a few pF, usually).  In the 1990s I made design using a CMOS 555 and a Philips polymer film sensor, the cap was in the 120pF range and varied by maybe 30pF. Temp compensation was the complex (and therefore at least mildly interesting) bit. These days we would use a microcontroller (a few PIC16Fxx have a built-in 555-ish peripheral).